# Select db column which contains a defined column in the same row

Tags: php, mysql

It might be a bit confusing but let me explain.

So I have this DB

```
ID | username  | status
1  | Bob       | On
2  | James     | On
3  | Jack      | Off
4  | Bob       | Off
5  | Arthur    | On
```

How can I echo all the names which include status on? I tried something like

```
$reponse = $pdo->query('SELECT username, COUNT(1) as CNT FROM   users GROUP BY  status;');
$donnees = $reponse->fetch();
foreach ( $reponse as $key => $value ) {
   echo '<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o">  '.$value['username'].'</i></a></li>';
}
```

Expected result

Echo:
Bob
James
Arthur

But it only prints out the 1st ID who is offline (in this case Jack).

Thank you

PS: I'm learning PHP/MySQL at this moment so I feel kinda lost, If you share an answer please explain why you use your code and where I was wrong thank you.

Comment: Why do you have duplicate entries in your Users table? Are these the same user? Or different users with the same name? Otherwise it's simply a case of using a WHWERE clause in a SQL statement: `select name from users where status='On'`

Comment: @AlivetoDie it does my db has username instead of name, sorry about that

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @RagingBull echo all on users, for example Bob, James and James

Comment: @MarkBaker from that code, no errors where shown but i don't have anything showing up

Comment: @DiogoJesus can you add expected result for your example.

Comment: @DiogoJesus - Well perhaps no users have a status set to "On" in your database table

Comment: @MarkBaker they do, at the moment i have them all with status "on"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your expected result, you don't need a `group by` here:

```
$reponse = $pdo->query('SELECT username FROM   users   WHERE  status="On"');
```

This will give you the result as :

```
username    
----------
Bob     
James   
James
```

If you want to count them:

```
$reponse = $pdo->query('SELECT username,count(1) as cnt FROM   users   WHERE  status="On" group by username');

username    cnt
----------------
Bob     1
James   2
```

Comment: only the last ID online is showing up, in this case the 2nd james

Comment: @DiogoJesus: In the expected result you commented under question, it was Bob, James and James. For clarification, please edit your question and add the expected result.

Comment: @MarkBaker everytime i change ' to " inside the ' quote otherwise the page doesn't load and just an error shows up

Comment: @DiogoJesus  what expected outcome you want actually? can you add that to your question? you are wasting time of every-one

Comment: @RagingBull your first code is giving up only 1 echo and that echo is the last ID name who is on, the other 2 on are not being shown.

Comment: @DiogoJesus: Please, add your expected result in the question.

Comment: @DiogoJesus: Well, looks like it is just a where clause needed. As shown in  the first part of my answer.

Comment: @RagingBull for some reason there's always 1 name missing even if he has the status "on" inside phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

```
$reponse = $pdo->query('SELECT username, COUNT(1) as CNT FROM   users   WHERE  status='On;');
$donnees = $reponse->fetch();
foreach ( $reponse as $key => $value ) {
echo '<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o">  '.$value['username'].'</i></a></li>';
}
```

Try this...Group by command may group your data by sorting off status first and then on status.

Comment: no errors where shown but nothing came up on the screen either

Comment: Is the status really `On;` or just `On`?

Comment: just On, but i did removed the ";" and still not working